# Clicking on a fading out element returns target.event body. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using https://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/ to generate tooltips to elements on my website.

I want some action to be executed every time a user clicks a tooltip, I'm using:

```
$(document).on('click', '#powerTip', function(event) {
    // do whatever
});
```

Now, sometimes it will fire the click event correctly, other times it won't. Somewhat randomly, or maybe when it's almost fading out. I tried debugging it, and event.target sometimes is #powerTip and sometimes it's just the body tag. Could someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: If you have multiple tooltips using an id is wrong. Use a class: `.powerTip`.

Comment: powertip library itself has this architecture.. I guess it's only one element that dynamically generates